# How can I find an URL of a Facebook page from its ID?

Tags: facebook

I know a Facebook page ID and I’d like to get a full URL to the page. The full URL looks like this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/page-title/numeric-id
```

I don’t know the `page-title`. If I drop it from the URL and just use the numeric ID, I get a 404. I can [call the Graph API](http://graph.facebook.com/208215118693) to get the full URL from the ID, but that’s too heavy (one extra HTTP request, JSON parsing). Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fimiliar with Facebook Application but I know a bit about it. If you're talking about the page title, then there is a "name" object in your response code. Get that, and replace the white space with - and place your ID. May be, It will work

```
    'http://www.facebook.com/pages/'.str_replace(' ','-',$name).'/numeric-id
// $name is your page name fetched from object.
```

Comment: The thing is, I don’t know the page title, the `$name`. All I have is the ID.

Comment: Make a call over the Graphi API as you suggested above that "I can call the Graphi API". That have the page name. Try it out.

Comment: Well if I’m already parsing the response, I might as well get the whole URL that’s a few lines below the name, right? The whole point of my question is to get the URL without calling the Graph API and parsing the response.

Comment: How can you place your page title without having it?